# carrierwave cache not resubmitting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

When I submit an image via Carrierwave, and am missing one field (i.e. the title), then the cached image will appear...

```
      <% if @post.avatar? %>
          <%= image_tag @post.avatar_url, :style => "width:300px"  %> 
          <%= f.hidden_field :avatar_cache %>
          <%= @post.avatar_url %>
      <% end %>
```

However, the :avatar_cache field is empty.  When I resubmit the form, none of the image properties move forward, so I have to reselect the image.

The issue is similar to this. [CarrierWave not saving upload after form redisplay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783904/carrierwave-not-saving-upload-after-form-redisplay) but there was no answer.

What is happening?  Thank you.

Comment: Did you white-listed the field avatar_cache?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? Having the same issue with Rails 4.1 and Carrierwave 3.

Comment: Same issue here. Anyone?

Answer (score 5):

For me, the issue was that I had

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :avatars, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: lambda { |avatar| avatar[:file].blank? }
```

So I was rejecting the file because the file wasn't there

**It is important to note that the file itself does not persist, but only the file cache. That is why the carrierwave [docs](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#making-uploads-work-across-form-redisplays) suggest:**

*It might be a good idea to show the user that a file has been uploaded, in the case of images, a small thumbnail would be a good indicator:*

Comment: This won't work if the form is being submitted remotely

Comment: This is a really helpful comment. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Check if you have an `attr_accessor` declaration for `avatar_cache` in your model. I added it by accident instead of `attr_accessible` (as mentioned in their docs) and it overrode the methods generated by CarrierWave.

Answer (score 0):

The carrierwave documentation is outdated for Rails 5+. Now that strong parameters are a part of Rails you have to white list `avatar_cache` in the controller. E.G:

`params.require(:user).permit(:name, :avatar, :avatar_cache)`

Also make sure you **dont** have `attr_accessor :avatar_cache` in model (that was my problem)

Answer (score -1):

Try populating the value of avatar_cache so that when validation fails, it will be pre-populated in the form:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :avatar_cache, :value => @post.avatar_cache %>
```

This seems to work for me when the same form is reloaded multiple times (i.e. when validation fails multiple times). I think they left this out of the documentation.